# SQL Server Count and Group-By Specific Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

There is a table `courses` with columns: `student` and `class`

We need to list out all classes which have more than or equal to 5 students.

For example, the table:

```
+---------+------------+
| student | class      |
+---------+------------+
| A       | Math       |
| B       | English    |
| C       | Math       |
| D       | Biology    |
| E       | Math       |
| F       | Computer   |
| G       | Math       |
| H       | Math       |
| I       | Math       |
+---------+------------+
```

My answer:

```
select class from
(
select class, count(distinct class) as number 
from courses
group by class
) as classandnumber
where number > 5 or number = 5
```

And the correct answer is:

```
SELECT
    class
FROM
    (SELECT
        class, COUNT(DISTINCT student) AS num
    FROM
        courses
    GROUP BY class) AS temp_table
WHERE
    num >= 5
```

And now I have 2 questions:

1. Why do we need to count student not class? I think my logic is also true: counting the frequency of each class to get how many times this class is chosen, which equals to how many people there are in this class.
2. Why distinct is necessary? How can student A takes Math class twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions - in the reverse order:

2 - `DISTINCT` is necessary as a student may take a class twice, for example if they failed it the first time.

1 - When you group by `class`, you count all the values of a field that have the same `class` value. If you `COUNT(DISTINCT class)` that number will be 1 (since only 1 class has the same `class` value). So you need to count `student` values instead to find the number of `student` values with that particular `class` value.

Note that a subquery is not necessary, the `COUNT` test can be located in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT class
FROM courses
GROUP BY class
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT student) >= 5
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7f41/1)

Comment: Ok now I get why distinct is necessay. But for my 1st question, I wrote the following code: `SELECT class, count(class)
FROM courses
GROUP BY class` It also shows that Math is 6 (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7f41/5)

Comment: @VivHuang apologies - I wrote the answer to the first question based on the use of `DISTINCT`. I should have made that clearer and answered the questions in the opposite order. You'll note when you group by `class` and `count(distinct class)` the results are all 1. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7f41/6, I've edited the answer to (hopefully) better explain this.

Comment: Ok now I understand why. Thank you!

Comment: @VivHuang no worries. I apologise for the earlier confusion, I should have spent more time reading my answer before I submitted it.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct logic should not be necessary, assuming that a given student can only be associated with a given class once:

```
SELECT class
FROM courses
GROUP BY class
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;
```

Note that you also don't need the subquery.  If a given student could be associated with the same class more than once, you would use the distinct count in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT class
FROM courses
GROUP BY class
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT student) > 5;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In this question we have counted students because the requirement of question is to find students and then we are grouping the result by classes which will result in finding the students present in each class...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.